# JQuery hide contextmenu on body click

Tags: javascript, jquery

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nj6xqq6s/)

I'm wanting to add two right-click hijack menus on my page and I have one somewhat working above.

Alike it does upon clicking inside of `.square`, I would like this menu to hide on body click regardless of right or left click.

### How can I hide this menu on body click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code.

```
 jQuery(document).click(function(event) {
   if (jQuery(event.target).closest('.square').length === 0) {
    //hide your menu here
    jQuery('.custom-menu').hide();
   }
  });
```

For right click add below code.

```
jQuery(document).on("contextmenu",function(e){
  if (jQuery(event.target).closest('.square').length === 0) {
    $('.custom-menu').hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: Is this additional code, not to replace any current? -- Works for left click but not right.

Comment: This is the additional code just add into your existing code. For contextmenu  event compatibility check here https://api.jquery.com/contextmenu/

Comment: Seems like my entire JSFiddle could be minimized a lot... I cannot argue that this works however so thank you :)

Comment: Just to save a little time, is all my code needed for a working version like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hp33g7pu/)

Comment: Yes, It is okay now.